# How to fix a math equation regarding doubles

Tags: c#

I am using visual studios with C# and I am trying to figure out a chemical energy equation.

To resolve the equation I have tried using setting variables as doubles, strings, and TextBox. In the calculation button, I have tried to `Convert.ToDouble`, parsing, but I keep getting the same three error. it is either a Nan error, format exception or 0.

```
#region variables
 // names for all variables
    string name;
    string material;
    string date;
    string time;
    TextBox joules; // maybe string or Text Box
    double kg;     // maybe string or Text Box  
    double msec;   // maybe string or Text Box msec.Text
    double totalJoules;
    double totalKg;
    double totalMsec;
    double totalP1Msec;
```

And

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // if kinetic energy clicked, use formula
  if (kineticEnergyCB.Checked == true ) // && double.TryParse(kineticEnergyCB.Text, out joules)

  {
  // If I recieve a format exception, then there is a problem in how the form is taking in the text
 totalJoules = Convert.ToDouble(kg) * 0.5 * Convert.ToDouble(msec) * Convert.ToDouble(msec);
   //  kineticEnergyTB = totalJoules;
   // kg.Text                 
    }
     else
     {
      // If mass clicked, use manipulated formula
      if (massCB.Checked == true ) // && double.TryParse(kineticEnergyCB.Text, out kg)
      {
       totalKg = 2 *Convert.ToDouble(joules.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(msec) * Convert.ToDouble(msec);
        //  massTB = totalkg;                 
       }
        else
        {
         // If velocity clicked, use manipulated formula
          if (velocityCB.Checked == true ) // && double.TryParse(kineticEnergyCB.Text, out msec)
         {
          totalP1Msec = 2 * Convert.ToDouble(joules) / Convert.ToDouble(kg);
           totalMsec = Math.Sqrt(totalP1Msec);
           // velocityTB = totalMsec;
          }
      }
 }
```

I am expecting that the formula takes the kg, joules, msec and multiply and 
divide accordingly. For example, if I am trying to calculate joules, the 
formula is `kg * 0.5 * msec * msec`. The formula should take the numbers from 
the textboxes and display a number, but I either receive 0 or Nan.

Comment: Your question is not clear. if `kg` is double already, why are you trying to Convert to double?

Comment: If you simply add a double variable in your class, it is initialized to 0.0. It has no relation to any input field. If you use it in a formula, you will receive 0 if you multiply by it, or NAN if you divide by it.

Comment: At which line in your code do you receive each of those corresponding errors? How are `kg` and `msec` getting their initial values?